# QGIS Split With Lines Gets Stuck at ca.70%

Tags: qgis

I've succesfully been using the *Split With Lines* tool to split contour polygon shapefiles into several chunks with a lines shapefile using QGIS 3.10.11, however since upgrading to 3.16.8 the process now gets stuck at around 70%

I've tried rolling back to the previous version and re-run on inputs that I know worked before but to no avail.

Any ideas what is causing this? Or alternatively is there another algorithm that can achieve the same result?

Comment: @BERA thanks for the suggestion - didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix by installing QGIS afresh on a different PC.

Install/package info for future reference:

- QGIS version: 3.10.0
- QGIS code revision: 6c816b4204
- Qt version: 5.11.2
- GDAL version: 2.4.1
- GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1
- PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018